# JBPM 7.31 reassign notifications

Tags: notifications, task, jbpm, reassign

In JBPM is possible to resend a notifications after a reassign operation?

Example:

This is an example of my process

[image: 1]

The Task Evolution is configured to send a notification to the potential owners.

If the task is not processed administrator user can reassign the task to a new group.

Here is an example of the  notification configuration

[image: 2]

My goal is that the notifications is sent to the new group.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can create new notification using kie-server REST API:

```
POST /server/admin/containers/{containerId}/tasks/{taskInstanceId}/notifications
```

You can define user/group details to which email can be send in the request payload:

```
{
  "from" : "test@jbpm.org",
  "reply-to" : "no-reply@jbpm.org",
  "users" : [ "john" ],
  "emails" : [ "emails@jbpm.org" ],
  "groups" : null,
  "subject" : "reminder",
  "body" : "my test content"
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a possible solution but in this case I should call 2 services (notification and reassignment).
Is there a possibility of capturing the reassignment event?

Comment: You can use taskReassignmentEvent from TaskEventListener https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-knowledge/blob/7.x/kie-api/src/main/java/org/kie/api/task/TaskLifeCycleEventListener.java#L70